# Remove right margin after positioned div to the middle

Tags: html, css, margin

I positioned my main div to `0 auto;` and still there is right margin what should I do to remove it?

Here is the fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/sz3MD/9/

```
body  {
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       background: #EEE;
       font: 10px/13px 'Lucida Sans',sans-serif;
    }

    .wrap {
       overflow: hidden;
       margin: 10px;
       background-color: #fff;
       margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .box {
       float: left;
       position: relative;
       width: 14%;


    }

    .boxInner img {
        background-color: black;
       width: 100%;
       display: block;
       -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
       -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
       -o-filter: grayscale(100%);

    }
```

Comment: thats sweet, but your fiddle doesn't work.

Comment: @MightyPork for me it does, i don't know what to do...

Comment: The images don't show up for me.

Comment: Are you talking about this margin? http://prntscr.com/22yeme

Comment: @AlcidesQueirozAguiar yes exactly this!

Comment: I think you have a right answer below... by @beautifulcoder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
.wrap {
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
}
.box {
  width: 14.25%;
}
```

The idea is enlarge box widths and set margins to make it "appear" without a right margin.

http://jsfiddle.net/sz3MD/10/

Answer (score 1):

@beautifulcoder solution is good but is not quite correct. This problem isn't related with `.wrap` margins or paddings, that "right margin" is really a part of the `.wrap` content.

There are 16 elements in the grid, if you calculate the total width in percentage of 7 `.box` elements (per row), each with 14% of width, the outcome is 98%, so the 2% remaining width of the total width is what you call "right margin" which is in fact part of the element content.

If you use 14.25% there is still a little blank space so you should use `14.285714286%` (the outcome of 100/7) instead of `14%` or `14.25%` to solve the problem. CSS allows you to use large numbers like this without problems so don't worry about the size.

Do not use `margin: 0 0 0 auto` either. As I have just explained is not a margin problem so you don't need this property. You can even remove the property `margin: 0 auto` unless you specify a width because as the width of the wrap is 100% it will never have margins.

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/sz3MD/13/) to demonstrate the differences between

```
.wrap {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 0 0 auto;
}

.box {
    width: 14.25%;
}
```

and

```
.wrap {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.box {
    width: 14.285714286%;
}
```